# PHP filter array by another true/false array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have this array:

```
$arr_to_filter = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15);
$filter = array(0, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

Expected result:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => 3 
       [1] => 5 
       [2] => 10 
)
```

I can achieve this by this loop:

```
$arr_to_filter = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15);
$filter = array(0, 1, 1, 0, 1);
$output_array = array();

foreach($arr_to_filter as $key=>$val) {
   if(isset($filter[$key]) && $filter[$key]) {
       $output_array[] = $val;
   }
}

print_r($output_array);
```

Can i achieve this using built in functions like [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) or another built in function without using loops?

Comment: "Built in functions like array_***" are made with loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PHP >= 5.6, you can take advantage of `array_filter()`'s third argument, allowing you to match keys with your filter set:

```
$arr_to_filter = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15);
$filter = array(0, 1, 1, 0, 1);

$result = array_filter(
    $arr_to_filter,
    function($key) use ($filter) {
        return !empty($filter[$key]);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);

var_dump($result);
```

If you're using an earlier version of PHP, then you need to filter on the keys, and intersect that result against your original array:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(
    $arr_to_filter,
    array_filter(
        array_keys($arr_to_filter),
        function($key) use ($filter) {
            return !empty($filter[$key]);
        }
    )
);
```

If you want to reset the keys after either of these methods, then just use `array_values()`

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_map`, `array_slice` and `array_reduce` functions:

```
$filtered = array_reduce(array_map(null, array_slice($arr_to_filter, 0, count($filter)), $filter),
    function($r, $a){
        if ($a[1]) $r[] = $a[0];
        return $r;
    }, []);

print_r($filtered);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 10
)
```

Comment: @semsem, actually, your `foreach` loop approach is not so bad in such case